# Nested Loops Time Analysis

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, nested-loops

Ok I am taking an Algorithm Class and am studying for the Exam...
Unfortunately.. I can't understand the concept behind the nested loops time analysis

there are three loops in this code

```
for (i=1->n)
 for (j=1->i)
   for (k=1->i)
     x=x+1;
```

I can't understand how to figure out the answer :s 
Any Answer would be a great help
Thanks Folks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `i=1`, k-loop runs 1 time and j-loop runs 1 time. Total=1.1=1 time
When `i=2`, k-loop runs 2 times and j-loop runs 2 times. Total=2.2=4 times
When `i=3`, k-loop runs 3 times and j-loop runs 3 times. Total=3.3=9 times
When `i=n`, k-loop runs n times and j-loop runs n times. Total=n.n=n^2 times

So, time complexity of algorithm is O(1+2^2+3^2+...n^2)=O(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6) =O(n^3)

Comment: Another Question please:

 for (i=1 - > n)
   for (j=1 -> i)
     for (k=1 -> j)
        //code here

Comment: @Umar Now figure out how to do it, just the way I did it. I wrote the answer in detail so that it is easier for you to learn.

Comment: Okay.. can u just check my answer, please??..

when i=1, j-loop runs 1 time and the k one runs 1 time so its 1.1=1
when i=2, j-loop runs 2 times and the k one runs 3 times so its 2.3=6
when i=3, j-loop runs 3 times and the k one runs 6 times so its 3.6=18

Comment: @Umar No, it is not correct. You are still missing the point. Basically, all that matters to you is how many times does the inner loop actually run where you are doing some operation (constant time operation). I wrote it in a step-by-step manner so that it is easier for you to figure out what is going on. For complex problems, you should be using Yochai's method. Anyway, I have solved it for you. See http://pastebin.com/s3mmGG2i

Answer (score 3):

You need to sum up the loops, it's a just multiple sigmas that need to be calculated:

[image: Sigma Calculation]

The **1** in the inner sigma is the complexity of what you're doing inside the innermost loop.

Comment: Sweet equations, but you got the second sum wrong. It's just i^2, not i(i+2)/2.